# Prove a proposition containing only the connective ∧,∨ is "monotonic"

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, examples-counterexamples

> For   an assignment   $v$ and  $i ∈ ℕ$, define  $v_{i}$
> to    be  the assignment  with    $v_{i}(x_{i})=T$  and
> $v_{i}(x_{k})= v(x_{k})$  for    every   $i ≠ k$. (So $v_{i}$ agrees   >with   $v$
> on    all variables,  except  possibly    $x_{i}$, which   it  sets    to  True).
>
> A proposition $ α$ is   said    to  be  monotone if for any assignment  $v$
> satisfying    $α$, it  holds   that    every    assignment $v_{i}$
> also  satisfies   $α$, for every $i ∈ ℕ$.
>
> Prove that    every   proposition containing  only    the connectives $∧,∨$
> (in   addition     to constants   and variables)  must    be  monotone.

The solution proves this with structural induction, but there is a thing I fail to understand in the proof, in the inductive step in the situation where $α = β ∧ δ$, where $β,δ$ are monotone strict subformulas of $α$, the claim the following

> $α = β ∧ δ$: Suppose $v$ is an assignment that satisfies $β ∧ δ$. This
> means that $v$ must satisfy both $β$  and $δ$. Since $β$ and $δ$ are
> each individually monotonic, we know for every $i ∈ ℕ$ that ***$v_{i}$
> satisfies $β$ and also satisfies $δ$***. By the truth table of $∧$,
> this means every $v_{i}$ satisfies $β ∧ δ$. That is, $β ∧ δ$ is
> monotonic.

Why does $v_{i}$ satisfy both $β$ and $δ$? We know that as $β$ and $δ$ are monotonic there exists a $v_{i}$ that satisfy $β$, and a $v'_{i}$ that satisfies $δ$, but I don't understand why there exists a single $v_{i}$ that satisfies them both? I feel like I'm missing something important in my understanding of the subject and I can't move on from it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $v_i$ is *totally determined* by $v$: it's the valuation you get by taking $v$ and modifying it (or leaving it alone) so that it assigns $T$ to $x_i$. There aren't two different versions of $v_i$ floating around, one for $\beta$ and one for $\delta$.

---

In detail, the argument is the following. Supposing $v$ is a valuation satisfying $\beta\wedge\delta$ and $i\in\mathbb{N}$, we want to show that *the uniquely define valuation* $v_i$ also satisfies $\beta\wedge\delta$.

- $v$ satisfies $\beta$ and $v$ satisfies $\delta$ (definition of satisfaction for $\wedge$).
- Since $v$ satisfies $\beta$, $v_i$ also satisfies $\beta$ (since $\beta$ is monotonic).
- Since $v$ satisfies $\delta$, $v_i$ also satisfies $\delta$ (since $\delta$ is monotonic).
- So $v_i$ satisfies $\beta\wedge\delta$.